# How can I center an image and text in the middle of a div?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="curbaT">
        <img src="avertizare/1.png" class="img" >
        <p class="p1">Curba la stanga - Este amplasat la cel mult 200 m de o curba la stanga. Conducatorul trebuie sa circule cu viteza redusa in curbe, iar daca vizibilitatea este redusa, toate manevrele (depasirea, oprirea, stationarea, mersul inapoi, intoarcerea) sunt interzise.</p>
   </div>
```

I have this and I want to have the image centered vertically, aligned to the left, and the text, centered vertically, but to be to the right of the image.

[I attached an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHh9A.png)
...and I tried that:

```
.img{

   left: 50;
   height: 100px;
   width: 120px;
   margin-top: auto;
   margin-bottom: auto;
}

.p1{
    position: absolute;
    right: 120px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this css with your existing HTML to achieve that:

```
.curbaT {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.img{
   margin-left: 50;
   height: 100px;
   width: 120px;
   margin-top: auto;
   margin-bottom: auto;
}

.p1{
    margin-right: 120px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

The `display:flex` and `align-items` centre the content vertically in a row.
You don't want to use absolute positioning in the inner elements because then they lose relation to each other, so use margins instead as above.

Answer (score 0):

For less and simple code, we can use **flexbox** feature. But, IE < version-11 doesn't support **flexbox**. For details, check this link -> [Flexbox support.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Coming to answer, please use the below CSS for achieving the desired result with your own HTML.

```
/* Basic properties needed */
.curbaT {
  display: flex; /*This is required*/
  align-items: center; /*This is required*/
  justify-content: center;  /*this is optional*/
  flex-direction : row;/*default value - optional*/
}
/*For beautification, please check the below snippet*/
```

```css
* ,*:before,*:afer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.curbaT {
  display: flex; /*This is required*/
  align-items: center; /*This is required*/
  justify-content: center; 
  flex-direction : row;/*default value*/
  border: 1px solid #888; /*this can be changed*/
  height: 130px; /*this can be changed*/
  padding-left: 30px; /*this is optional*/
  padding-right: 30px; /*this is optional*/
}
.curbaT img { 
  margin-right: 20px; /*this can be changed*/
}
```

```html
<div class="curbaT">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x70" class="img" >
        <p class="p1">Curba la stanga - Este amplasat la cel mult 200 m de o curba la stanga. Conducatorul trebuie sa circule cu viteza redusa in curbe, iar daca vizibilitatea este redusa, toate manevrele (depasirea, oprirea, stationarea, mersul inapoi, intoarcerea) sunt interzise.</p>
   </div>
```